# What should I put as the context - FFmpeg - Android/Java

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am following [the documentation for FFmpeg here](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) and I am wondering what I should put as the context?

#### My function

```
public static void conversion(String[] cmd) {

FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context); //what should I put as the context here?

try {


  // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
  ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }
  });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
  // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And then I call my function like this (from the same class):

```
public void alert(String message) {
      String[] cmd = {"-i"
              , message
              , "Image.gif"};
      conversion(cmd);
  }
```

Comment: I'd use the `Application` context, as they (probably) are not doing anything with the `Context` that involves the UI, and they might be using this to initialize a singleton (so any other `Context` would represent a memory leak). But, I haven't used this library, so I don't know if that approach causes any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing that in an `Activity`, you can pass the `Activity` instance by passing `this`. Or if the `context` instance will outlive the lifetime of the `Activity`, you can pass `Application` context as `this.getApplicationContext()`

```
FFmpeg.getInstance(this);

FFmpeg.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Update:

```
public class AndroidApplication extends Application {

    private static AndroidApplication sInstance;


    public static AndroidApplication getInstance() {
      return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();  
      sInstance = this;
    }


}
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add this line in the `application` tag:

```
android:name="yourPackage.AndroidApplication"
```

Now you can pass the `AndroidApplication.getInstance()` as `context`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! However when I ran your code I got an error: `cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Perhaps you have that method inside a static method. Where are you calling this method? In an Activity?

Comment: Can you remove that static keyword for the method?

Comment: alright sure, Sorry about the confusion - I am very new to android development. I have updated my question.

Comment: now I am getting `Error:(37, 40) error: incompatible types: RNGifMakerModule cannot be converted to Context` any ideas? thank you so much for helping me

Comment: Is `RNGifMakerModule` is the name of the class? From where are calling the method `conversion()`

Comment: Yes, the class is `RNGifMAkerModlue`. Would it be helpful if I just posted the whole script?

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1218  . And subclass the Application class. Pass that sInstance from the Application class as the context.

Comment: Thank you! will do.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful, I have followed what you said, and it worked! Now I have one more question (sorry). I am getting this error: `Error:(43, 31) error: cannot find symbol class ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler` any idea as to why/how to fix?

Comment: It looks like a different issue. Would you mind posting it as a separate question with necessary code and error messages?

Comment: Sure, Here is is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549701/ffmpeg-cannot-find-executebinaryresponsehandler-android-java thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

context should be your activity context or application context. If you are using it inside a fragment, you can do `getActivity()` which will return activity context. If you are using it inside Activity you can do `YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this`