# FFmpeg - cannot find ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler - Android/Java

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a module for react-native that will change a video into a gif. I have little to no experience with android studios/java, but I would love to learn more! I am using [this library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) to convert the video to a gif. Here is my code:

```
package com.reactlibrary;

import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg;

public class RNGifMakerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public RNGifMakerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "RNGifMakerModule";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void alert(String message) {
      Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      String[] cmd = {"-i"
              , message
              , "Image.gif"};
      conversion(cmd);
  }

  public void conversion(String[] cmd) {

    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this.reactContext);

    try {


      // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
      ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }
      });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
      // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Error:(43, 31) error: cannot find symbol class ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler
```

This seems odd to be, because in [the documentation for ffmpeg-android-java](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) it says to use *almost* exactly the same code.

#### Bounty

The bounty will be awarded to you if you can find a way to convert a video.mp4 into a gif. You **do not** necessarily have to use `FFmpeg`, but your solution has to work with java/android studios.

Comment: Have you imported that `ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler`?

Comment: Well... No, I thought that would be included in ...libffmpeg.FFmpeg

Comment: Can you post your entire class and the entire error message?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll do it in about an hour when I get to work.

Comment: I guess you should import that class separately. `import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler`

Comment: And make sure you have this line in build.gradle: `compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'`

Comment: I have included that line in build.gradle. When I tried to add `import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ExecuteBinaryResponseHan‌​dler` it did not recognize it. I have updated my question with **all** of my code. (side note: I figured out thanks to the tutorial you showed me in my previous question that I was supposed to use `this.reactContext` as my context). thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should init ffmpeg correctly.

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this.reactContext);

// please add following method after

ffmpeg.loadBinary(new FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                // probably your device not supported
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // you should init flag here (isLoaded, isReady etc.)
            }
```

Only after `onSuccess()` you can work with commands.

Then please check following [answer](https://superuser.com/a/556031) by LordNeckbeard.

So your code should be something like this:

```
if (isFFmpegLoaded) {
    // ffmpeg.execute(commands from link from the answer) 
}
```

Please do not forget to remove all spaces from command's string and "ffmpeg" word.
To keep command more readable I will recommend to build command like this:

```
final String[] command = new String[11]; // example of the first command in the answer
        command[0] = "-y";
        command[1] = "-ss";
        command[2] = "30";
        command[3] = "-t";
        command[4] = "3";
        command[5] = "-i";
        command[6] = "-t";
        command[7] = "filePath";
        command[8] = "-vf"; 
        command[9] = "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen";
        command[10] = "palette.png";
```

Please make sure that you have storage permission to work with file just in case you are working on external storage.

Based on this strategy ffmpeg works well for me. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! However I am getting this error when I try the code you provided: `Error:(48, 27) error: cannot find symbol class FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use: File - Invalidate Caches/Restart - Invalidate and Restart and try to reimport `ExecuteBinaryResponseHan‌dler`. If the problem hasn't been resolved you can try the small hack. Inside your project create package `com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg` and class:

```
public class ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler implements FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}
```

It should be as on image:

[image]

Then inside your build.gradle file in `defaultConfig` block add `multiDexEnabled true`

[image]

Then you will be able to use that class

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did the first part, but before I have done the second part, I realized that I do not think I imported it properly (Actually I did not import anything). What should I do to import the library?

Comment: Could you give me a github link to a working version of your project?

Comment: I am looking at the repository now. Thank you so much for making it! I am getting this error " `Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/zoe/Developer/tmp/FFmpegSample/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip
<a href="openFile:/Users/zoe/Developer/tmp/FFmpegSample/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>` any ideas, if not thats fine. Thank you again!

Comment: Try to use Gradle wrapper. File - Settings - Build, Execution, Dep.. - Gradle and select 'use default gradle wrapper (recommended)'. Also, disable instant run: File - Settings - Build, Execution, Dep.. - Instant Run and unmark 'Enable instant run to hot swap...'

Comment: I did that and it sort of worked, but I got this error (below link). I would really like to award you the bounty because of all the help you gave me. let me know what you think of this error when I build my app: https://imgur.com/a/0NL0C thanks again for the help. project screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2TN3x

Comment: The first part of the error is telling about a version of Android Studio, you should use the latest stable (it's 2.3.3 [Android  Studio 2.3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)) or latest beta (it's 3.0 [Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html)) I suggest you use the latest stable. The second part is telling about "Instant run", how to disable it I wrote above (in the second part). I think the problem is in the version.

Comment: I for some reason could not get the sources you provided to work again... I asked another question on them. Feel free to answer or not answer it, I just thought that I would let you know. Thanks again for the help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019490/cannot-link-executable-ffmpeg-android