# CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE - ffmpeg - Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I am getting the following error when I try to use ffmpeg on Android.

#### Error

```
09-02 18:06:33.805 2861-3659/com.gitlab.onreg01.ffmpegsample D/FFmpeg: Running publishing updates method
09-02 18:06:33.917 2861-2861/com.gitlab.onreg01.ffmpegsample D/LOG_FFMPEG_SAMPLE: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/com.gitlab.onreg01.ffmpegsample/files/ffmpeg": "/data/data/com.gitlab.onreg01.ffmpegsample/files/ffmpeg" has text relocations
09-02 18:06:33.943 2861-2861/com.gitlab.onreg01.ffmpegsample D/LOG_FFMPEG_SAMPLE: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/com.gitlab.onreg01.ffmpegsample/files/ffmpeg": "/data/data/com.gitlab.onreg01.ffmpegsample/files/ffmpeg" has text relocations
```

#### Platorms

I am running OSX (not sure if this is important)

I have tried running the app on the following emulators all to no avail:

- Nexus 5X - API 25 - x86
- Nexus 5X - API 23 - x86
- Pixel 5X - API 26

#### What I have tried

- Restarting my computer and android studios and running `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`
- Using all of the following sources for ffmpeg (individually and together):

  - `compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'`
  - [AAR file from here](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/)
  - [`.jar` file from here](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=a%3A%22ffmpeg%22&a=ffmpeg)
- Enabling and disabling NDK
- Changing the SDK versions

#### [Sources](https://gitlab.com/onreg01/FFmpegSample/tree/master/)

In case you would like to take a look at the sources, the ones I am using are available [here](https://gitlab.com/onreg01/FFmpegSample/tree/master/). Please note **I did not make these** all credit goes to [**@Onregs**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5455375/onregs).

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I have a similar issue that I am researching at the moment. It seems to be emulator reladed for me. If anyone has a solution or answer that would be great.